# Get specific indices of Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
X = [-10000, -1000, -100, -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
l = np.where(np.array(X) > 100)[0]
```

So i have

```
l = array([ 9, 10], dtype=int64)
```

Now I want to get a new Array X with the elements of l as indices. I want to get:

```
X = [1000, 10000]
```

I thought of:

```
X = X[l]
```

But it does not work. What  is the proper function to use in this case? I don't want to use a for loop.

Comment: I'm tempted to "close" this because it needs 'debugging details'.  You should show the error, instead of just say "it does not work".  The error might help you understand the problem.  `X` is a list.  It can only be indexed with integers (or slices).  If you make an array to get the `where`, you can also use that array to get the desired values.

Comment: Use a list comprehension if you don't want to use arrays: `[x for x in X if x>100]`
`

Comment: To be pickie again.  The subject line talks `indices of Array`. Which array?  `A` is a list!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your list `X` into a numpy array before you can index it with a list of indices:

```
>>> X = np.array(X)[l]
>>> X
array([ 1000, 10000])
```

Comment: But what if I also want to do it for bigger arrays? Or I don't know the elements in l? Is there no function that can provide what I want to do?

Comment: While there may be a function, and you could use a list comprehension (`[X[i] for i in l]`), using numpy is bound to be the most efficient and fasted way. numpy is excellent at handling very large arrays.

Comment: What does bigger arrays or not knowing `l` have to do with this.  That `l` can be used to select elements from an array like `np.array(X)`.  It can't be used to select elements from the list without some sort iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert list X to numpy array

```
x=np.array(X)
```

and then use indexing

```
x=x[x>100]
```

This will get the result you need without using where() function

"x>100" expression creates a boolean array with True elements corresponding to the elements of x array which are larger than 100. This array can be used as index to extract elements satisfying the condition.